# How do I retrieve user information from discord.js events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Right now I'm working on a Discord bot ignore command will ignore a channel's command inputs when this action is true. Right now my current js file is [here](https://github.com/Game-Corner/GC-System/blob/version-0.0.2/bot.js).

What I need the bot to do is:

1. Detect when the message "GCMignore" is posted
2. Find if their role is "Moderator".

Right now I'm not able to get retrieve the user who sent the message to detect if they are a moderator. I've tried `guildmember.roles` and I understand how a map works, it's just that the code is not able to relate back to the person who sent the message.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, @turmuka . Apparently, the ReadTheDocs for discord.js is outdated and the one on their site is not. user.hasRole() doesn't work but I did some more research on maps and I found I can use guildMember.roles.has('role') from the role object.

Comment: nice, I like it, can you link me to that site @SethDeegan

Comment: Here @turmuka : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Answer (score 1):

See this [link.](https://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_user.html)

You can use `User.hasRole()` function to see what roles they have. Also to be able to create roles please see this [link](https://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#memberhasrole-member-role)